# I need to combine 2 functions to remove white flash on IFRAME reload

Tags: javascript, iframe

I currently use 2 scripts. The first to hide the initial white flash on the first load of the iframe:

```
<script>
// Preventing whiteflash in loading iframes.     
(function () {
    var div = document.createElement('div'),
        ref = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0] || 
              document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    div.innerHTML = '&shy;<style> iframe { visibility: hidden; } </style>';
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(div, ref);
    window.onload = function() {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    }
})();
</script>
```

The second script reloads the iframe every 15 seconds:

```
<script>
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 15000);
function reloadIFrame() {
 document.getElementById("MY_IFRAME").src="XYZ";
}
</script>
```

I need to combine the two if possible so the subsequent reloads of the iframe do not show the flash. The first load works perfectly.

I can only use a script and having 2 iframes alternate on load after loading in the background is an option, I just don't know where to start with that.

Any help appreciated, bit of a java newbie, so the simpler the better!

Comment: is it only in the case of first load? or after every 15 seconds ?

Comment: The first load works perfectly, with no white flash. The reloads every 15 seconds have a white flash on reload that i want to get rid of.

Comment: Okay! Can you add a kind of video recording somewhere !

Comment: here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bonesey2000/qdte3njL/4/ (hopefully I have done this right, my first use of fiddle)